# Python - Find distinct domains inside a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list (with dictionaries inside) and I want to know how many different domains are inside it.

I have something like this:

```
list = [
    {'url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions', 'number': 10},
    {'url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/users', 'number': 40},
    {'url': 'https://stackexchange.com/tour', 'number': 40}, 
    {'url': 'https://stackexchange.com/whatever/whatever', 'number': 25}
]
```

The desired result would look like this:

```
unique_domains = [
    {'url': 'https://stackoverflow.com'},
    {'url': 'https://stackexchange.com'}
]
```

Or maybe just:

```
unique_domains = ['stackoverflow.com', 'stackexchange.com']
```

Both would be OK, so whatever is easier or faster I guess.

I think I could use Regex for this, but maybe there are more pythonic and/or efficient ways to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) (from standard library) together with set comprehension (to avoid duplicates):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

unique_domains = {urlparse(item['url']).netloc for item in given_list}
```

If you need, you can convert `set` to `list` via `list(unique_domains)`. This is more reliable than regex solution.

(please don't call variable `list`, it shadows useful builtin).

Comment: That's great, thanks! I thought it would be more difficult.